# MSSQL select where following (sequence) rows with the same column value as current column equale to X

Tags: sql-server

how do i do a select where count = select all sequence rows has the same column value as current column value only if there 3 in sequence (row after row with no holes)

```
NAME    |   NUM     |   DATE
---------------------------------
Name 1  |   1   |   '2019-01-07 12:11:11:001'

Name 2  |   1   |   '2019-01-07 12:11:12:002'

Name 3  |   3   |   '2019-01-07 12:11:13:003'

Name 4  |   2   |   '2019-01-07 12:11:14:004'

Name 5  |   2   |   '2019-01-07 12:11:15:005'

Name 6  |   2   |   '2019-01-07 12:11:16:006'

Name 7  |   4   |   '2019-01-07 12:11:17:007'

Name 8  |   5   |   '2019-01-07 12:11:18:008'
```

**The results should be where count sequence=3**

```
NAME    |   NUM     |   DATE
---------------------------------
Name 4  |   2   |   '2019-01-07 12:11:14:004'

Name 5  |   2   |   '2019-01-07 12:11:15:005'

Name 6  |   2   |   '2019-01-07 12:11:16:006'
```

because 2 appears 3 times in sequence

Comment: please share the table schema, sample data and expected result

Comment: Sample data and expected results are going to help here. Your description is far too vague to even begin to be able to answer. Please do include your attempts when you edit your question too.

Comment: I've added a sample / table schema

Comment: Which column determines sequence in your table? Is it `[date]`? If yes, then how are same-date records ordered?

Comment: The num column (the date is just to order by)

Comment: My question is about which column is used to determine `ORDER`ing. If `[date]` is used, then how do you order records having the same date value (like your sample data)?

Comment: Order by date (i added times in dates)

Comment: Those sample times are useless for a datetime. The datatime datatype is only accurate to .003 so most of those time values are actually the same. The question here is not all that difficult. But you have provided so little in the way of definition of the problem I don't understand what you want.

Comment: I changed the time again........... The time is only for the ORDER BY,
After sorting (order by) we need to check sequence with same num one after one that apears 3 times

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT [NAME], [NUM], [DATE],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE]) - 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NUM ORDER BY [DATE]) AS grp
FROM mytable
```

to get:

```
NAME    NUM DATE                    grp
----------------------------------------
Name 1  1   2019-01-07 12:11:11     0
Name 2  1   2019-01-07 12:11:12     0
Name 4  2   2019-01-07 12:11:13     3
Name 5  2   2019-01-07 12:11:14     3
Name 6  2   2019-01-07 12:11:15     3
Name 3  3   2019-01-07 12:11:16     2
Name 7  4   2019-01-07 12:11:17     6
Name 8  5   2019-01-07 12:11:18     7
```

As you can see calculated column `grp` can be used in order to identify islands of consecutive records having the *same* `NUM` value.

You can then wrap the above query in a `CTE` and do:

```
;WITH GroupCTE AS (
   SELECT [NAME], [NUM], [DATE],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE]) - 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NUM ORDER BY [DATE]) AS grp
   FROM mytable
)
SELECT t.*
FROM GroupCTE AS t
JOIN (SELECT NUM, grp
      FROM GroupCTE 
      GROUP BY NUM, grp
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 3) AS g ON t.NUM = g.NUM AND t.grp = g.grp
```

Comment: i have this table